# how to set marker one by one in google map api v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, settimeout, marker

I am doing a google map which will read a set of coordinates and put the marker on the map one by one.

Below is my idea:

```js
function A{
   for loop( 
      set marker
      call setTimeout('A',2seconds)
   )    
}
```

my idea is to set a marker and use setTimeout to wait 2 seconds and then set the next marker.

However, it doesn't work. it show all the markers at the same time and repeat to renew all markers.

How can i achieve my goal?
Thanks for your help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Here is my code:

```js
function marker(){
    var marker;
    var i=0;

    while(i<locations.length){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map
            });
        i=i+1;
        var t=setTimeout("marker()",2000);
    }
}
marker();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return after setting the first marker. You also need a parameter to A which specifies which marker to show.

```js
function marker(i){
    if (i > locations.length) return;

    var marker;

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map
        });

    var t=setTimeout("marker("+(i+1)+")",2000);
}
marker(0);
```

Comment: can you tell me what should i add in the program? return at where?
and i am not really clear about " need a parameter to A which specifies which marker to show."

Comment: See my updated version of your code (note that I haven't tested it, but this should work)

Comment: Thanks Micheal, it works.
can you explain more what is the meaning of the syntax:marker("+(i+1)+")?

Comment: The marker function now takes a parameter which is the index of the marker to display. Instead of just calling `marker()`, you now need to call `marker(i+1)` since `i` is the index of the marker just displayed, and you want to display the following marker. `"marker("+(i+1)+")"` simply constructs this string.

Comment: Note that I just realized a key error in my solution. You need to ensure that the function stops calling itself after all markers are displayed. The first line I just added accomplishes this task.