# setTimeout every time a marker is added

Tags: javascript, google-maps, settimeout

I am trying to implement some "forced animation" in a google map, by showing the marker being added one by one.

For this i used the following code.

```
function Marker(i) {
    if(i > locations.length) return;                
    var populationOptions = {
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 0.8,
         strokeWeight: 2,
         fillColor: '#FF0000',
         fillOpacity: 0.35,
         map: map,
         center: citymap[locations[i][1]].center,
         radius: citymap[locations[i][1]].population
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);

    var t = setTimeout("Marker("+(i+1)+")",2000);
}
Marker(0);
```

I've taken this example from: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605440/how-to-set-marker-one-by-one-in-google-map-api-v3) , but Firebug says the function Marker is not defined on the line of setTimeout();

Any ideas?

Updated Code:

```
function Marker(city) {
    alert(city);
    var populationOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: citymap[city].population
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
}

for (city in citymap) {
    var t = setTimeout(function(){Marker(city);},2000);
}
```

I assumed that every time Marker was called, it would have a delay of 2 seconds, but that is not the case. It waits 2 seconds and the run the for all in once. Also the "city" doesn´t update, adding the same marker x times the number's of citys in citymap.

The for cycle doesn't wait for the timeout to finish?

Comment: Your timeout is inside Marker() so this bug

Comment: I updated the code! The code was taken by an example, and it was supposedly working for the OP.

Comment: @user2342275 Is citymap array or object...??

Comment: citymap is a object with .center / .population / atributes

Comment: Citymap is an object or array of objects...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
var count = 0;
function Marker() {
    city = Object.keys(citymap)[count];
    alert(city);
    var populationOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: citymap[city].population
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
    count++;
}
var i =1;
for (var city in citymap) {
    var t = setTimeout(function(){Marker();},i*2000);
    i++;
}
```

And you have declared citymap as `var citymap = {}`.. Modify it as `var citymap = [];` in line 38

Comment: Because setTimeout makes your function to work only once after the specified milliseconds .. 2000 means your function will be executed n times after 2 seconds .. so you should go i*2000 which makes your function to work aftr 2,4,6 seconds

Comment: @user2342275 i can pass the city value only if you say whether it's an object or array of objects or post your citymap value

Comment: The for doesn't wait for the function to return. How can i make this synchronous? citymap value? citymap value is [object Object], it does not have a representation.

Comment: You can modify Marker() function accordingly to work but i need to know the structure of citymap json

Comment: Sorry i'am not understanding. citymap is an "class"? with two atributes: population and center. The identification is running by the name of city: citymap[city]. Is that it? Sorry if can't explain better...

Comment: City is integer or string ...??

Comment: See my edited answer and say whether it works .. If not , say what you gets for alert(city);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29595/discussion-between-prasath-k-and-user2342275)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a new city added every 2 seconds and not repeat calling your Marker funciton even after it's done processing all items in citymap you can do the following (also gets rid of the global counter variable)

```
function Marker(count) {
    city = Object.keys(citymap)[count];
    console.log(city);
    var populationOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: citymap[city].population
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
    count++;
    if(count<citymap.length){
        setTimeout(function(){Marker(count);},2000);
    }
}
Marker(0);
```

Comment: Updated my answer so it works like you want it to. And doesn't need to declare 2 extra global variables for it to work